# HTML луна не на том месте

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!
У меня есть проблема с расположением луны в моем меню на сайте,
вот скриншот как хочу чтобы было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавлял просто отступ справа и он был там где нужно, но когда я масштабировал сайт то он сразу уезжал влево, а должен был подождать пока до него дойдут рамки страницы и тогда и себе идти

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p, h1, h2, h3, footer, img, ol, ul, table {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

header {
  background-color: var(--header-back-col);
  color: rgb(158, 154, 154);
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}

#menu ul li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(158, 154, 154);
}

.toggle-theme {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: var(--toggle-bg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
  filter: brightness(150%);
  transform: var(--toggle-theme-transform);
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:root {
  --text: #333;
  --toggle-bg: url(https://i.postimg.cc/bwT9gJv1/moon.png);
  --header-back-col: #222;
  --a-menulogo-hover: brightness(200%);
  --toggle-theme-transform: rotate(250deg);
  --toggle-theme-hover-filter: brightness(390%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <element id="menu">
      <ul class="content">
        <a href="index.html" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; line-height:1px; margin-left: 25px;">
          <img style="display:inline-block;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Ikea_logo.svg/800px-Ikea_logo.svg.png" width="100" alt="logo" class="menuHeader">
        </a>
        <li><a href="">IKEA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">IKEA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">IKEA</a></li>
        <button class="toggle-theme"></button>
      </ul>
    </element>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <br>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код в ваши стили:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.toggle-theme{
    float: right;
}
```

Объясняю:

1. вы позиционируете родительский элемент
2. в дочернем элементе центрируете его по правому краю